# Moving an image on a canvas with arrow keys

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, eventhandler

I'm trying to get a block I've called "Sword" to move up and down when using the arrow keys, I have event listeners and handlers but for some reason they're just not talking to each other and I dunno why.

Here is the HTML, it's very simple, just draws a canvas to use.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>17013455_assignment_2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <script src="17013455_ass2_task1.js"></script>
</html>
```

This is the Javascript, the canvas has a background drawn on, and the "sword" is drawn as a box, my key handlers should move the sword on the Y axis depending on the sword's height and it's space in the Y axix.

```
window.onload=function () {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var gc = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width = 640;
    canvas.height = 448;
    gc.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var background = new Image();
    background.src = "https://i.imgur.com/9mPYXqC.png";


        //sword dimentions
        var swordHeight = 50;
        var swordWidth = 25;
        var swordX = 50;
        var swordY = 220;

        //controls for player
        var upPressed = false;
        var downPressed = false;

        if (downPressed && swordY < canvas.height - swordHeight) {
            swordY += 10;
        }
        else if (upPressed && swordY > 0) {
            swordY -= 10;
        }

    function keyUpHandler(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 38) {
            upPressed = false;
        }
        else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
            downPressed = false;
        }
    }

    function drawSword() {
        /*Make a box to represent a sword until sprites are used*/
        gc.beginPath();
        gc.rect(swordX, swordY, swordWidth, swordHeight);
        gc.fillStyle = "#000000";
        gc.fill();
        gc.closePath();

    }

    function keyDownHandler(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 38) {
            upPressed = true;
        }
        else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
            downPressed = true;
        }
    }

    function render() {
        background.onload = function () {
            gc.drawImage(background, 0, 0)};
        drawSword();

    }

    document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, "false");
    document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, "false");

    render();
    setInterval(render, 10);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move this part of code

```
if (downPressed && swordY < canvas.height - swordHeight) {
        swordY += 10;
    }
    else if (upPressed && swordY > 0) {
        swordY -= 10;
    }
```

to render() function.
Your function should look like this:

```
function render() {
    if (downPressed && swordY < canvas.height - swordHeight) {
        swordY += 10;
    }
    else if (upPressed && swordY > 0) {
        swordY -= 10;
    }
    gc.drawImage(background, 0, 0)};
    drawSword();

}
```

and this part

```
background.onload = function () {
        gc.drawImage(background, 0, 0)};
```

to window.onload = function(){} scope

Comment: Thanks! The buttons are working now, but when I press them the block just gets bigger down the Y axis instead of moving up and down it.

Comment: You need to redraw the background, add this line gc.drawImage(background, 0, 0)}; before drawSword();

Comment: Thanks very much!